# Keras/TensorFlow equivalent of PyTorch Conv1d

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch

I am currently in the process of converting a PyTorch code to TensorFlow (Keras). One of the layers used is Conv1d and the description of how to use it in PyTorch is given as

```
torch.nn.Conv1d(in_channels: int, out_channels: int, kernel_size: Union[T, Tuple[T]], stride: Union[T, Tuple[T]] = 1, padding: Union[T, Tuple[T]] = 0, dilation: Union[T, Tuple[T]] = 1, groups: int = 1, bias: bool = True, padding_mode: str = 'zeros')
```

where as in Keras (TF1.15) the description is given as

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=1, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=1, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, **kwargs)
```

I have not been able to reproduce the same output I get in PyTorch in TensorFlow. i.e. for the sample code in PyTorch

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import numpy as np

B, K, L, N = 4, 10, 128, 64
mixture = torch.randint(3, (B, K, L), dtype=torch.float32)
# L2 Norm along L axis
EPS = 1e-8
norm_coef = torch.norm(mixture, p=2, dim=2, keepdim=True)  # B x K x 1
norm_mixture = mixture / (norm_coef + EPS)  # B x K x L
# 1-D gated conv
norm_mixture = torch.unsqueeze(norm_mixture.view(-1, L), 2)  # B*K x L x 1
conv1d_U = nn.Conv1d(L, N, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=False)
conv_out = conv1d_U(norm_mixture)
conv_out = F.relu(conv_out)  # B*K x N x 1
mixture_w = conv_out.view(B, K, N)  # B x K x N

weights = conv1d_U.weight.data
```

In TensorFlow to get similar dimensions for the output the code can be found below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_net():
    # Encoder
    mixture = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 128), name='mixture', batch_size=4)  # [B,K,L]
    norm_coef = tf.keras.backend.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.sum(mixture ** 2, axis=2, keepdims=True) + 1e-8)  # [B,K,1]
    norm_mixture = mixture / norm_coef  # [B, K, L]
    norm_mixture = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(tf.keras.backend.reshape(norm_mixture, [-1, 128]), axis=2)  # [B*K,L,1]
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', use_bias=False, name='conv')(norm_mixture)  # [B*K,N,1]
    mixture_w = tf.keras.backend.reshape(conv, [4, -1, 64])  # [B, K, N]
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=mixture, outputs=mixture_w)

model = build_net()
weights = model.get_weights()
inp = np.random.randn(4, 10, 128)
out = model.predict(inp)
```

Comparing the dimensions of the weights in either case the Conv1d operation is clearly different than TensorFlow (Keras), how should the TF code be changed to reflect the same operation?

Comment: Why should the weights be the same? In any case, weight initialisation depends on the pseudo random generator used by either framework.

Comment: I am not expecting the weights to be the same, I would like the operation to be replicated. The dimensions of the weights is a proxy to check if the Conv1d kernels will result in similar operation. I have changed the forming of the question to reflect this

Comment: The number of in channels is not provided in Conv1D in keras (it is derived from the previous layer, the input layer in this case). `filters` is the number of out channels:

`conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', use_bias=False, name='conv')(norm_mixture)`

Comment: @Max that is what I thought I should do from the documentation, however the output dimension of Conv1D operation is (40,128,64) but in PyTorch we get the output of dimension (40,64,1). So again the operation being performed on the data does not match.

Comment: I see. The thing is that keras uses the "channel last" format, i.e., the last dimension is always the number of channels/filters/feature maps in convolutional layers. The dimension before is the sequence dimension in 1D-convolutional layers. 

Please check my suggestion below, only the expand_dims axis needs to be modified, actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def build_net():
    # Encoder
    mixture = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(10, 128), name='mixture', batch_size=4)  # [B,K,L]
    norm_coef = tf.keras.backend.sqrt(tf.keras.backend.sum(mixture ** 2, axis=2, keepdims=True) + 1e-8)  # [B,K,1]
    norm_mixture = mixture / norm_coef  # [B, K, L]
    norm_mixture = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(tf.keras.backend.reshape(norm_mixture, [-1, 128]), axis=1)  # [B*K,1,L]
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu', use_bias=False, name='conv')(norm_mixture)  # [B*K,1,N]
    mixture_w = tf.keras.backend.reshape(conv, [4, -1, 64])  # [B, K, N]
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=mixture, outputs=mixture_w)

model = build_net()
print(model.summary())
weights = model.get_weights()
inp = np.random.randn(4, 10, 128)
out = model.predict(inp)
```